# What do the numbers on the scale mean when I zoom in and out

Tags: satellite, resolution, pixel

I am using a map that overlays carbon emissions over geographies produced by a satellite. When I zoom in and out, the number on the "scale" changes. I want to know what this number actually means. For example, when I zoom in the most, I get the following image:

[image]

On the bottom right, the number says "100 m". Now when I zoom out once, I get the following image:
[image]

The number becomes larger and is now "200 m". When I zoom out once again, I get the following:

[image]

The number now becomes "300 m". What do these numbers mean? From my own digging around, it seems it refers to the size of a pixel of the image, e.g., 100 m means that each pixel is 100 m x 100 m. But what does this mean exactly? What does a "pixel" mean in each of these images? How big is a pixel?

Comment: It is a scalebar. The length of the labeled rectangle is 100, 200, or 300 meters.